# Moviepy, extract clips faster

Tags: codec, moviepy

Windows 10, moviepy, python 3.8

I am trying to create subclips from a video. 
I originally tried:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
clip = VideoFileClip("video1.mp4").cutout(0, 7)
clip.write_videofile("test.mp4")
```

That took so long to run. It did run though
Someone suggested:

```
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip
ffmpeg_extract_subclip("video1.mp4", start_time, end_time, targetname="test.mp4")
```

I couldn't get it to run? At first I had to update ffmpeg, and I did that. I also registered pip so I could do updates.

However, now I am getting this error:

```
[mp4 @ 065cd280] Could not find tag for codec pcm_s16be in stream #1, codec not currently supported 
in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Last message repeated 1 times
```

I know it is a codec error. How do I fix this? I am on windows.